# MySQL How can I select get specific status and else get last ID if not meet requirement status?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen solutions for something similar on other posts, but I am having an issue applying it to my problem.

I have this table for voucher last history:

`t_release`:

`+------------+---------+----------------+-------------------+
| release_id | code_id | code_status_id | code_created_date |
+------------+---------+----------------+-------------------+
|          1 |      32 |              2 | 4/28/2016 8:54    |
|          1 |      32 |              2 | 4/28/2016 8:54    |
|          2 |      32 |              3 | 4/28/2016 8:55    |
|       3710 |      32 |              2 | 6/18/2016 10:20   |
|          4 |      33 |              2 | 4/28/2016 9:54    |
|          5 |      33 |              2 | 4/28/2016 10:54   |
|       3711 |      33 |              2 | 6/18/2016 11:20   |
|          6 |      34 |              2 | 4/28/2016 11:54   |
|          7 |      34 |              3 | 4/28/2016 0:54    |
|       3712 |      34 |              2 | 6/18/2016 0:20    |
+------------+---------+----------------+-------------------+`

And

`r_code_status`:

`+----------------+-------------+
| code_status_id | code_status |
+----------------+-------------+
|              1 | Available   |
|              2 | Requesting  |
|              3 | Paid        |
+----------------+-------------+`

When I running:

```
SELECT 
t1.release_id,
t1.code_id,
t1.code_status_id,
t1.code_created_date
FROM t_release t1
LEFT JOIN t_release t2 ON t1.code_id = t2.code_id AND t1.release_id < t2.release_id
WHERE ISNULL(t2.release_id)
```

`+------------+---------+----------------+-------------------+
| release_id | code_id | code_status_id | code_created_date |
+------------+---------+----------------+-------------------+
|       3710 |      32 |              2 | 6/18/2016 10:20   |
|       3711 |      33 |              2 | 6/18/2016 11:20   |
|       3712 |      34 |              2 | 6/18/2016 0:20    |
+------------+---------+----------------+-------------------+`

I need if code_id meet `code_status_id = '3'` or 'Paid', the query can retrieve it as last history, else if `code_id` with `code_status_id = '2'` then last `id(release_id)` retrieved.

I want the result like this:

`+------------+---------+----------------+-------------------+
| release_id | code_id | code_status_id | code_created_date |
+------------+---------+----------------+-------------------+
|       2    |      32 |              3 | 4/28/2016 08:55   |
|       3711 |      33 |              2 | 6/18/2016 11:20   |
|       7    |      34 |              3 | 4/28/2016 0:54    |
+------------+---------+----------------+-------------------+`

DDL:

```
create table t_release (
release_id INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
code_id INTEGER(11) DEFAULT NULL,
code_status_id TINYINT(4) DEFAULT NULL,
code_created_date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`release_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC CHARACTER SET 'utf8';

INSERT INTO t_release
(`release_id`,`code_id`,`code_status_id`,`code_created_date`)
VALUES
(1, '32', '2', '2016-4-28 8:54'),
(2, '32', '3', '2016-4-28 8:55'),
(3710, '32', '2', '2016-6-18 10:20'),
(4, '33', '2', '2016-4-28 9:54'),
(5, '33', '2', '2016-4-28 10:54'),
(3711, '33', '2', '2016-6-18 11:20'),
(6, '34', '2', '2016-4-28 11:54'),
(7, '34', '3', '2016-4-28 0:54'),
(3712, '34', '2', '2016-6-18 0:20');
```

and this is link sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87843

Comment: what is the datatype of `code_created_date`?

Comment: datatype of code_created_date is DATETIME. i've added the DDL and link sqlfiddle

Comment: is there any chance that multiple records are having `code_status_id = 3` under the same  `code_id`?

Comment: No it isn't, no chance for multiple records for code_status_id = 3 under the same code_id.

Comment: except code_status_id = 2 will having under the same code_id. because the client app can trigger button request many times and recorded. if paid, the message appear on the client app and can't request again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM t_release t where release_id IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT release_id FROM t_release WHERE code_status_id = 3)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t_release t where release_id IN 
    (SELECT MAX(release_id) FROM t_release x WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t_release y WHERE code_status_id = 3 and y.code_id = x.code_id))
   GROUP BY code_id)
```

First query will fetch all those that are paid, the other will fetch the last release_id of those that remain unpaid.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `MySQL user defined variables`

```
SELECT 
t.release_id,
t.code_id,
t.code_status_id,
t.code_created_date
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
  *,
  IF(@sameCodeID = code_id, @rn := @rn + 1,
     IF(@sameCodeID := code_id, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
   ) AS row_number
  FROM t_release t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sameCodeID := 0, @rn := 1) AS var
  ORDER BY code_id, code_status_id DESC, release_id DESC
) AS t
WHERE t.row_number <= 1
ORDER BY t.code_id
```

---

<kbd>[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87843/9/0)</kbd>